# How to solve "Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option: Non-existent pathname: /bin/which" & blocking unattended-upgr during Debian10->11 upgrade?

Tags: debian, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I was trying to upgrade Debian 10/KDE to Debian 11 bullseye stable via `sudo apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs`

The output was:

```
Preparing to unpack .../dh-autoreconf_20_all.deb ...
Unpacking dh-autoreconf (20) over (19) ...
Setting up aide-common (0.17.3-4) ...
Replacing config file /etc/cron.daily/aide with new version
cp: cannot remove '/etc/cron.daily/aide': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package aide-common (--configure):
 installed aide-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up dh-autoreconf (20) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 aide-common
Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option: Non-existent pathname: /bin/which
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'if [ -x /usr/bin/rkhunter ] && grep -qiE '^APT_AUTOGEN=.?(true|yes)' /etc/default/rkhunter; then /usr/share/rkhunter/scripts/rkhupd.sh; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I then removed aide (`sudo apt-get remove aide`) and tried again, after installing it says this:

```
Invalid SCRIPTWHITELIST configuration option: Non-existent pathname: /bin/which
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'if [ -x /usr/bin/rkhunter ] && grep -qiE '^APT_AUTOGEN=.?(true|yes)' /etc/default/rkhunter; then /usr/share/rkhunter/scripts/rkhupd.sh; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I then tried again but now `unattended-upgr` is running and it doesn't quit after waiting for a while, after running "End Process" in the process manager or sending a KILL signal to it (even though now it's only one instead of two unattended-upgr processes).

It seems to have mostly run through as `lsb_release -a` returns Release: 11.

Are these errors problematic or should I simply restart for it to be solved? And if so, shouldn't there be some message that a restart is needed (or a better error message)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re running into a problem with `rkhunter`, tracked as [Debian bug #932594](https://bugs.debian.org/932594).

In short, `rkhunter.conf`’s paths don’t match your system’s. You’ll need to edit it to fix the path to `which`:

```
sed -i s,SCRIPTWHITELIST=/bin/which,SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/which, /etc/rkhunter.conf
```

To stop `unattended-upgrade`, kill it with

```
killall -9 unattended-upgrade
```

then look for any stray `apt`- or `dpkg`-related processes, and kill them too if they don’t exit in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: To put simply the solution is to edit `/etc/rkhunter.conf` and change `SCRIPTWHITELIST=/bin/which` to `SCRIPTWHITELIST=/usr/bin/which` (the path displayed when running `which which`), save the file and rerun the command. However, if that's correct that's not solving the problem of unattended-upgr blocking the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You have **rkhunter** installed and configured to run every time you do operations with apt. Edit the `rkhunter.conf` and see if `SCRIPTWHITELIST` is set to `/bin/which`. There would be multiple entries there. Change it to the right path for `which`.
Or you can remove rkhunter from running every time you execute apt.

Answer (score 0):

The location of `egrep` and `fgrep` seems to have moved from `/usr/bin` to `/bin`. The easiest thing to do get things going for you is just symlink to the old location

```
sudo ln -s /bin/egrep /usr/bin/egrep
sudo ln -s /bin/fgrep /usr/bin/fgrep
```

And then it was able to get passt the `SCRIPTWHITELIST` issue.